# TypeError: Cannot read property 'positive' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass an object from one component to another. I can access all the way down to sentiment_scores but sentiment_scores.positive is undefined. Props is first passing as undefined then passing the props in again with the object. Can someone help me to retrieve sentiment.positive? Thanks

**Parent Component**

```
export class Metrics extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            results: {},
            loading: false,
            user: this.props.location.state.detail
        } 
        this.dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        this.docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    }

    onRead = () => {
        let that = this;
        let params = {
            TableName: "prod_metrics"
        };
        this.docClient.scan(params, function(err, final) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
            else{
                final.Items.map(item =>{
                    if (item.user === that.state.user){
                        that.setState({ results: item});
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        this.setState({ loading: true});
    };

    render() {
    if (!this.state.loading){
        return (
        <div>
            {setTimeout(this.onRead, 5000)}
            <div className="spinner">
                <MDSpinner size={100}/>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
        return(
            <div className="Metrics">
                <div className="TwitterHandle"><TwitterHandle name = {this.state.results} /></div>
                <div className="Mapping"><Mapping/></div>
                <div className="Keywords"><Keywords name = {this.state.results}/></div>
                <div className="Hashtags"><Hashtags name = {this.state.results}/></div>
                <div className="Ratio"><Ratio name = {this.state.results}/></div>
                <div className="Score"><Score name = {this.state.results}/></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Metrics;
```

**Child Component**

```
export class Score extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isMouseInside: false,
        };
      }

    mouseEnter = () => {
        this.setState({ isMouseInside: !this.state.isMouseInside });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Scores-div">
                <div className="SentimentInfo">
                    <button className="Sentiment-button" onClick={this.mouseEnter}><img src={info} alt="info" height={24} width={24}/></button>
                    </div>
                    {this.state.isMouseInside && 
                    <div className="ScoreHover">
                        <h3>Percentage based scores of sentiment values</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <p>Each emoji represent a different emotion</p>
                            <p>Percentages based on overall sentiment scores</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>}
                <div className="SentimentScores">
                    {console.log(this.props.name.sentiment_scores.positive)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    } 

}

export default Score;
```

** Object being passed **

```
{sentiment_ratio: "1:4",
sentiment_scores: {negative: "80.0", positive: "20.0"},
top_hashtags: (2) ["{x:#ドミノピザ, y:48}", "{x:#ドミノウルトラチーズ, y:24}"],
top_keywords: (5) ["{x:#ドミノピザ, y:48}", "{x:これからも, y:48}", "{x:をよろしくお願いします, y:24}", "{x:をよろしくお願いします, y:24}", "{x:明日もチャレンジできます, y:24}"],
user: "dominos"}
```

Comment: `onRead` is a async func, so on page load `this.props.name.` this will be default, i.e `{}` and `.sentiment_scores` is not defined in it. Hence it breaks. Add a check if the value exists then only process

Comment: @Rajesh Great thank you! will certainly try that! Thanks